# Excel Pivot table Data Model measure for displaying a value without calculation

Tags: excel, pivot-table, powerpivot

I am confused on how to build a Pivot table relating different Excel tables. The solution might be simple, but I am lost!
Say we have 3 tables for dealing with human resources:

- a table for required activities (each has 2 levels)
- a table for human resources, people and their working rate (partial time or full time)
- and a 'junction table' for person_activities where we insert the actual working load of each person on each level.

[image]

The model is [image]

I want to build a Pivot table like the following one, with a hierarchy person/activity/level (in compact form) for checking that the sum of levels is not over the expected working rate of each people. We want to highlight people whose cumulated activities are over their working rate.

[image]

Should I use DAX measures and KPI for dealing with it? (king of `SUMX`? I don't master DAX formulas alas!). Maybe I am on the wrong direction? Any help welcome!

Comment: Why are your expected results for `x|b|level1` and `x|b|level2` 0,2 and 0,5 respectively? Looking at *table_hr_activity* I would expect them to be 0,8 and 0,5. And how precisely is *table_required* supposed to be involved? Your expected results seem to derive solely from the other two tables.

Comment: Sorry, I changed 0.8 for 0.2 value and forgot to update the source table. I am correcting now.

Comment: Your are right about _table_required_, but it's its real shape and is used another measure. I was able to compare expected levels with actual levels (with `SUMX`), but cannot do it with person[working rate]. I simplified my tables, but maybe not to the bare minimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to generate your desired hierarchy, you'll need to first modify *table_hr_activity*, e.g. via `Power Query`, **unpivoting** the *level1* and *level2* columns, which will give you something like:

| person | activity | level | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x | a | level1 | 0.3 |
| x | a | level2 | 0.2 |
| x | b | level1 | 0.2 |
| x | b | level2 | 0.5 |
| y | a | level1 | 0.5 |
| y | a | level2 | 0.3 |

After you've added this new table to the Data Model, go to the Power Pivot window (relationships view), click on the *person* field within this table and select 'Create Hierarchy'. Add the *activity* and *level* fields from the same table to this hierarchy.

Then create the following measure:

```
WorkingRate :=
VAR ThisPerson =
    MIN( table_hr_activity[person] )
RETURN
    LOOKUPVALUE(
        table_human_resources[working rate],
        table_human_resources[person], ThisPerson
    )
```

You can now create a Pivot Table with the hierarchy you created in the Rows section, with Sum of value (from the newly created table) and the above measure in the Values section.

***Edit**: to return the Working Rate at only the top level of the hierarchy:*

```
WorkingRate :=
VAR ThisPerson =
    MIN( table_hr_activity[person] )
RETURN
    IF(
        ISFILTERED( table_hr_activity[activity] ),
        BLANK(),
        LOOKUPVALUE(
            table_human_resources[working rate],
            table_human_resources[person], ThisPerson
        )
    )
```

Comment: Thank you, it works fine! I still don't understand the DAX measure. I had tried with `RELATED` with no success and didn't know about `LOOKUPVALUE`. Why does `MIN` work? I would have used `MINX`... I haven't grasped DAX indeed!

Comment: One of the main issues is that you can't simply rely on the existing relationship between *table_human_resources* and *table_hr_activity* to pull in the *working rate* values, since filtering in Power Pivot only ever propagates from the one side to the many side of a relationship, i.e. the *person* field from *table_human_resources* cannot filter *table_hr_activity*.

Comment: Is there a way to show the _WorkingRate_ only on the _person_ row int the Pivot Table? Repetition of the _WorkingRate_ is fine, but not the optimal view.

Comment: Sure - added an amended version of the measure to the post.