# Excel Pivot table Data Model avoiding duplicated column

Tags: excel, pivot-table, powerpivot

Closely related to my own question [Excel Pivot table Data Model measure for displaying a value without calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77222346/excel-pivot-table-data-model-measure-for-displaying-a-value-without-calculation), I get a pivot table where an empty column is repeated for each measure.

I do have 3 tables :

- a table for employee required activities (each has 2 levels)
- a table for human resources, employee and their working rate (partial time or full time), both in present and what is expected in 2 years.
- and a 'junction table' for person_activities where we insert the actual working load of each person on each level.

[image]

Thanks to [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77222346/excel-pivot-table-data-model-measure-for-displaying-a-value-without-calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77222346/excel-pivot-table-data-model-measure-for-displaying-a-value-without-calculation#answers-header) answer, I was able to build a correct Pivot table, BUT some columns are repeated when I include the expected working rate in 2 years:

[image]

I would like something like the following single Pivot Table which would only show relevant columns:

How to filter columns? Is it feasable at all? and if yes, how? Should I build 2 Pivot tables?
[image]